# Possible combinations - order is important

Tags: matlab

I want to create a table which contains all possible combinations, order **is** important, of N numbers in sets of k using matlab.

I tried `Combinations = combntns(set,subset)` and `Combinations  = perms(v)` and `Combinations  = combnk(v,k)`but in those order is not important.

An example:

> > nchoosek(1:5,3)

ans =

```
 1     2     3
 1     2     4
 1     2     5
 1     3     4
 1     3     5
 1     4     5
 2     3     4
 2     3     5
 2     4     5
 3     4     5
```

While it should also include

```
 1     3     2
 1     4     2
 1     5     2
 1     3     5
 1     5     3
...
```

The number of possible combinations is given by the following by the function:

N!/(N-k)!

[source: Mathisfun.com](http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations-calculator.html)

Is there a possible way to do it this using matlab functions?

Comment: The reason why you didn't find the solution before is that you were looking for combinations. Actually if the order matters it is referred to as permutations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this memory efficient solution:

```
n = 5; k = 3;
nk = nchoosek(1:n,k);
p=zeros(0,k);
for i=1:size(nk,1),
    pi = perms(nk(i,:));
    p = unique([p; pi],'rows');
end
```

`p` *should* contain what you are describing.  At least `size(p,1) == factorial(n)/factorial(n-k)` or `60` for this example.

Answer (score 0):

try this, if k = 3:

```
combvec(1:N,1:N,1:N)'
```